# Override Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation with Custom Block class makes product list dissapear

Tags: php, magento

I am doing a Magento website where the client has specific requirement on how they want the sidebars to be shown.

The catalog category default and the catalog search results will compose the sidebar menu items in different ways, which I have created my own module with block classes called Leafcutter_Catalog_Block_Navigation_Category_Navigation and Leafcutter_Catalog_Block_Navigation_Search_Navigation respectively. Both of these classes extend the default Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation. Here is the config.xml file for the Module:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Leafcutter_Catalog>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Leafcutter_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_toolbar>Leafcutter_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                    <!--<navigation>Leafcutter_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>-->
                    <product_list>Leafcutter_Catalog_Block_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
                <class>Leafcutter_Catalog_Block</class>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <category>Leafcutter_Catalog_Helper_Category</category>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </helpers>
    </global>
```

As you can see I have used the `<class>Leafcutter_Catalog_Block</class>` declaration as I don't want use `<rewrite>Mage_Catalog_Block_Nagvigation</rewrite>` as I assume that I would lose the ability to use my newly created Custom block classes.

I have also written some extra code in my local.xml file in my layout directory to accommodate one of my newly created blocks in their repspective correct pages.

```
<catalog_category_default>
            <reference name="product_list">
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="left">
                <block type="catalog/navigation_category_navigation" as="catalog.polar.vertnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/vertnav.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </catalog_category_default>
        <catalog_category_layered>
            <reference name="product_list">
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="left">
                <block type="catalog/navigation_category_navigation" as="catalog.polar.vertnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/vertnav.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </catalog_category_layered>
```

Now after applying these changes to the code, My sidebar works perfectly as expected. However, the problem now is that when in the catalog category page the catalog/product_list does not render at all and has completely dissapeared. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

My guess is that `<class>Leafcutter_Catalog_Block</class>` have been overtaken by that module.

So my question is how do I get this sidebar effect as you can see in the screenshot, whilst I have my listing of products and that I fulfil the requirement from the client that I render the sidebar of the catalog category pages in one way using my Leafcutter_Catalog_Block_Navigation_Category_Navigation block and the search results the Leafcutter_Catalog_Block_Navigation_Search_Navigation block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to your module:

```
<class>Leafcutter_Catalog_Block</class>
```

will cause the rewrite of all the blocks that start with `catalog/..`. You should remove that and rewrite only the blocks you need rewritten.

```
<blocks>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <block_alias_here>New_Class_Name_Here</block_alias_here>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</blocks>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Marius. I do understand your answer, I think part of the question has been answered in that I would have to use rewrite. However, I have the Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation as default and I need to override that class with the Leafcutter_Catalog_Block_Navigation_Category_Navigation for the catalog category pages, whilst with search results would use Leafcutter_Catalog_Block_Navigation_Search_Navigation class. So in saying that in your answer is it possible to even do what I have said or would it have to take significant rewriting to achieve this task?